# How to add external library over google API in ordering in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to add an external library in my Android Studio project. I have added it, but I want to set its order above Google API.
Right now, Google API is being shown as an external library, and the libs I am adding cannot be set above Google API in the ordering.
It was possible in Eclipse, but how to do it in Android Studio?

To be more precise: I am rewriting some Android framework classes and want to use them instead of the default Android framework classes. That's why I want to set the order of my lib above the Android API libs. Anyone have an idea how to do this?  I have done this in Eclipse by setting the order of my lib at the top.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio File - > Project Structure 
Select your app

Select dependencies(5th TAB).

There is a arrow button on the right of Window. select your library and order the dependencies

Comment: Alternatively you can change inside build.gradle dependencies tag

Comment: it does not set order of library over google API libs. Have tried it. also tried with build.gradle

Comment: I have overridden some android framework classes and want ot use them instead of default android framework classes.